# Issue with ADO.NET plus SQL Server Compact 3.5 database

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I'm now using SQL Server Compact 3.5 as my local database (in order to make it compatible and running on PCs without SQL Server installed). And I tried to use ADO.NET and Entity Framework to write connection services. However, I found some issues, for example I was trying to save a new object, it looks succeed, but it's actually not really going into the database. I feel it's like just storing in memory or something (when I re-run the project, the data is still there but it's not in the database).

My environment is: SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 + Visual Studio 2010.

EF code should be correct and is quite simple:

```
using(TestEntities te = new TestEntities()) {
    SystemUser su = new SystemUser();
    su.id = 1;
    su.name = "123";   
    te.AddToSystemUsers(su);
    te.SaveChanges();
}
```

I used the same code but with the database in SQL Server Management Tools, it works fine.

Can someone help me explaining with this? Is there any ways to solve the problem?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the database file as content, and each time you debug, it is copied to the bin/debug folder. To solve this, I recommend using a full path in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so what shall I do to successfully save the data into the database file?

Comment: Updated reply just now